# check if tables has same columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a Database that creates day tables and some of the tables don't have the same number of columns and in some cases the columns aren't the same.  What I'm needing to do is consolidate all the tables into a single table.  I'm not quite sure how to do this, but I'm assuming I need to make sure all the tables have the same columns and then add all the data from the multiple tables to the single table should be fairly easy.

so my first step, find out which tables are different and which ones are the same.

what I need is to find out if a table has the same columns as another.  not the data, but rather like the column names and possibly the data type for that column.

any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.  I'm manually going through these and checking the content, but would definitely like something that would be much quicker.

---

UPDATE

the table's have a date related naming scheme.  here's one for an example: `repo_2012_08_04`

Comment: Do your tables share a common naming scheme at least? Can you give some details about how you would identify the set of tables you want to compare?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I've updated the question with the table naming scheme.  about identifying tables =>  I could narrow the search to date ranges to help identify when the table generation process was updated/changed, but aside from that I'm not quite sure what you are wanting.

Comment: And do you have more details about the differences, e.g. is it possible for some tables to have more columns and others to be fewer, are you just concerned about column names, or also data types / precision / scale / nullability / defaults etc.?

Comment: Mostly some tables have more columns than others and some of the columns have changed names over time.  I'm not so worried about the data types.

Comment: Can you identify a table that has the "ideal" list of columns? It is much easier to compare against some known model than to just show all the differences that may exist between a bunch of tables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the one provided in the update as an example has the "ideal" list of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach if all you care about is column names and merely identifying any tables that have the same naming scheme but have columns that don't exist in the "model" or "ideal" table (also, I kept this simple, assuming all tables are in dbo):

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.repo_2012_08_04(a INT, b INT); -- model
CREATE TABLE dbo.repo_2012_08_05(a INT, b INT); -- same schema as model
CREATE TABLE dbo.repo_2012_08_06(a INT, c INT); -- different
CREATE TABLE dbo.repo_2012_08_07(a INT, b INT, c INT); -- different
GO

DECLARE @model SYSNAME = N'repo_2012_08_04';

SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE name LIKE N'repo[_]%'
AND name <> @model
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns AS c 
    WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
      WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@model))
      AND name = c.name
    )
);
GO

DROP TABLE repo_2012_08_04, repo_2012_08_05, 
           repo_2012_08_06, repo_2012_08_07;
GO
```

Results:

```
repo_2012_08_06
repo_2012_08_07
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the CHECKSUM() and CHECKSUM_AGG() functions. Though not perfect (checksums aren't, by definition), you'll get a pretty nice resultset to look at, where you can quickly spot the differences.

```
SELECT tbl.[name], CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(col.[name], typ.[name], col.max_length,
                                         col.[precision], col.[scale])) AS chksum
FROM sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS col ON tbl.[object_id]=col.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.types AS typ ON col.user_type_id=typ.user_type_id
GROUP BY tbl.[object_id], tbl.[name]
ORDER BY tbl.[name];
```

Go ahead and add any columns you would find relevant to the CHECKSUM(), such as collation order, whether the column is nullable, etc. If you have a "master" table that you want to compare the others to, put this query in a CTE, and do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM cte AS masterTbl
INNER JOIN cte AS tbl ON masterTbl.[name]!=tbl.[name]
WHERE masterTbl.[name]='masterTbl' AND masterTbl.chksum!=tbl.chksum
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would give you all the different tables, that have the same column name:

```
SELECT t.[name], c.[name], t2.[name]
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.[object_ID] = t.[object_ID]
INNER JOIN sys.tables t2 ON c.[name] = t2.[name]
WHERE c.[object_ID] <> t2.[object_id]
```

But it would be better to provide a list of the column names you are after, adding something like this to the statement:

```
AND c.[name] IN ('<column name 1>', '<column name 2>',...)
```

You can also check the column types by using:

```
AND c.[name] = '<column name>' AND c.[user_type_id] = 56
```

The user types in the above you can resolve by looking at the types in the sys.columns table (I can't remember exactly where you can resolve the types, will update if I remember!)